# how to set different font style on different UIlabel text line in ios using core text

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel, core-text

I want to make label format line this dynamic shape of label text word on different size how to use core text framework

please show this type format on dynamic shape generate on [Dynamic arrange  label text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd1JF.png)[Diffent font style arrange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbKHj.png)

please suggest on coustom library to make this type format

Comment: Use NSAttributedString with label.attributedText instead of label.text

Comment: i used NSAttributed string but not make proper formate like this ..so suggest  other option..or method

Answer (score 0):

I just show you the direction with NSAttributedString, you have to figure out rest of the fine details like correct fonts, sizes, styles, line spacing etc. (hint: check NSMutableParagraphStyle)

```
    let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
    attr.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "The\n", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(60), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.greenColor()]))
    attr.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "HAPPINESS OF\n", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(45), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]))
    attr.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "YOUR LIFE\n", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(40), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.purpleColor()]))
    attr.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "DEPENDS UPON", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.brownColor()]))
    label.attributedText = attr
```

[image]

Comment: @RGE  yes , than make possible but i want to make character space in "YOUR LIFE" to line length upper line "HAPPINESS of" equal length dynamatically to make both line Equal length..

Answer (score 0):

Using objective-C, you need to make 4 NSMutableAttributedString with different font names and sizes and then append them using "appendAttributedString" in order to get the desired result. Using this approach, you only need to make one frame for all strings.

See the code below for reference.

```
//frame that contains all text
textFrame = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[textFrame setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[textFrame setNumberOfLines:0];
[self.view addSubview:textFrame];

NSString *text1 = @"THE";
NSString *text2 = @"\nHAPPINESS OF";
NSString *text3 = @"\nYOUR LIFE";
NSString *text4 = @"\nDEPENDS UPON";

//change font name and size according to your need.
UIFont *text1Font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:10];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString1 =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text1 attributes:@{
NSFontAttributeName : text1Font}];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle1 = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle1 setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[paragraphStyle1 setLineSpacing:4];
[attributedString1 addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle1 range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString1 length])];

UIFont *text2Font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:16];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString2 =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text2 attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : text2Font }];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle2 = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle2 setLineSpacing:4];
[paragraphStyle2 setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[attributedString2 addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle2 range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString2 length])];

UIFont *text3Font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString3 =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text3 attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : text3Font }];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle3 = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle3 setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[attributedString3 addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle3 range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString3 length])];

UIFont *text4Font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString4 =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text4 attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : text4Font }];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle4 = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle4 setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[attributedString4 addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle4 range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString4 length])];

[attributedString1 appendAttributedString:attributedString2];
[attributedString1 appendAttributedString:attributedString3];
[attributedString1 appendAttributedString:attributedString4];

[textFrame setAttributedText:attributedString1];
[textFrame sizeToFit];
//change frame size as per your need.
[textFrame setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 136, 97)];
```